# Finding unit vector perpendicular to U

Tags: multivariable-calculus

given u=[0,4,3]T a unit vector  that is prependicular  to u is

How can I find the normal?

I am new to these stuff.

Thanks

Comment: In tridimensional space there are a plane of perpendicular vectors to $u$.

Comment: Just find "by inspection" any vector which has a zero scalar product with your vector. Then divide by its length to get a unit vector.

Comment: what if they ask for a vector parallel to u

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/133177/finding-a-unit-vector-perpendicular-to-another-vector

there is complete answer ,please see it

Comment: please see answer if it is enough

Comment: so if i want to find normal to <-10,-2,-8> ---> -10x-2b-8c=0 what do I do after?

Answer (score 0):

ok  in your case  vector is simple $u=[0,4,3]$,for some vector s,we say that  $s$ is perpendicular to   $u$,if $s*u=0$,so let us suppose that

$s=(s_1,s_2,s_3)$  ,so we have

$S_1*0+s_2*4+s_3*3=0$,

after that follow this rule

[Finding a unit vector perpendicular to another vector](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/133177/finding-a-unit-vector-perpendicular-to-another-vector)

Comment: so if i want to find normal to <-10,-2,-8>                   -10x-2b-8c=0                                                  what do I do after?

Comment: choose any values  of $x$,$b$ and $c$ which satisfy these solution,but  to gain unit vector,divide this vector by its length